# WebSphere Outbound FTP adapter doesn't work on IIS

Tags: iis, ftp, websphere, adapter, subdirectory

As is clear from the title, we are developing some applications on WebSphere ESB 7.5 by using FTP Adapter. When we try to create a new file on a ftp directory, we get the following error

> ResourceException thrown in J2CMethodBindingImpl.invoke() javax.resource.spi.InvalidPropertyException: Adapter failed to check permission on the specified directory.Either the DirectoryPath does not have the necessary permissions for outbound operation or the long listing provided by the FTP server differs from the standard format.

By using the same username/password pair I can view/edit/remove and create files under these folders. The strange part is, when I update configuration as:

> Host: 10.10.0.78, Directory:

There is no problem. But when I do this

> Host: 10.10.0.78, Directory: /test

I get the exception. Any suggestion ?

Details:

> FTP Server is Windows / IIS 7
>   WebSphere Application Server 7.0
>   ESB 7.5.1.1
>   FTP Adapter 7.5.1
>   Integration Designer 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as:

• Write a new customParserClass that extends org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.NTFTPEntryParser. 
• Add this to build path of the FTP Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

After I changed the listing type from MS-DOS to UNIX from IIS, it worked. 
But the technical documents say by changing the Custom Parser Class Name to "com.ibm.j2ca.ftp.util.FTPLongListEntryParser" is another solution. 
I tried that one, but still no progress.

I having some classNotFoundException but I'm still working and I let you know the updates...